# How to pass a variable from a Windows Batch File to SQL*Plus

Tags: windows, oracle, batch-file, oracle11g, sqlplus

I want to pass a variable from a Windows Batch File to SQLPLUS, 
while displaying sql result batch variable should print along with the sql result.

Result should be stored in csv file.

How can I do that.

This is possible in Unix(shell script) how can I do that in Windows(batch script).

Comment: Just pass it as an **argument to the SQL script** and use `substitution variables`. And to store the result set as CSV file, use `SPOOL` and format as `set colsep ,`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I want to pass a variable from a Windows Batch File to SQLPLUS

Just pass it as an argument to the SQL script. And use substitution variables in the same order that of the arguments list `&1 &2...`

For example,

**mybatchfile.BAT:**

```
sqlplus -S username/password@sid
@c:\sql\mysqlfile.sql 1000 7369
```

**mysqlfile.SQL:**

```
update emp set sal = &1 where empno = &2
```

> while displaying sql result batch variable should print along with the sql result.

To display the variables which you pass as arguments to the SQL script, first you need to define the bind variables, then assign the argument value and then print the value.

For example,

I have **test.sql:**

For **NUMBER type**

```
-- define the bind variable
var sal number

-- assign the first argument's value
exec :sal := &1

-- display the value
print :sal

-- define the bind variable
var empno number

-- assign the second argument's value
exec :empno := &2

-- display the value    
print :empno
```

Now, let's test the script:

```
SQL> @D:\test.sql 1000 7369

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.


       SAL
----------
      1000


PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.


     EMPNO
----------
      7369

SQL>
```

For **STRING type**

```
-- define the bind variable
var ename varchar2(10)

-- assign the argument's value
exec :ename := '&1'

-- display the value
print :ename
```

Now, let's test the script:

```
SQL> @D:\test.sql LALIT

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.


ENAME
--------------------------------
LALIT

SQL>
```

> Result should be stored in csv file.

Handle this in the SQL script. Use proper SQL*Plus formatting for comma separated result. To store the result set, you just need to `SPOOL`

For example,

```
set colsep ,     -- separate columns with a comma
set pagesize 0   -- No headers
set trimspool on -- remove trailing blanks

spool mycsvfile.csv

SELECT ....

spool off
```

Comment: i don't want to use use them into the query i just want to display that variable. like say variable is character string which i want to display in sql output.

Comment: See the updated answer. I have added an example how to display the argument value. Please mark it answered, would help others too.

Comment: can u please explain how to define characters as bind variables?

Comment: Ok, I have added examples for number type and string type respectively. See my updated answer.

Comment: its not working for characters, its giving an error PLS 0021 identifier must be declared.