# Append variable everytime while displaying oracle output

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, sqlplus

I have following mysql.sql sql script. I want to print dbname everytime with each statement of sql result.

How can I do that?

Also I want to add errors handling in the script.

mysql.sql

```
set colsep ',';
set trimout off;
set pagesize 0;
set trimspool off;
set feedback off;
set heading on;

spool C:sql_data\res_pre.csv app
var ename varchar2(20)

exec :dbname := '&1'

print :dbname
select '&dbname',user_name, user_id from employee where  designation = 'manager';

spool off
exit;
```

currently output is:

```
db1
abc 123
xyz 231
db2
efg 143
rst 234
```

I want output as follows:

```
db1 abc 123
db1 xyz 231
db2 efg 143
db2 rst 234
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> var ename varchar2(20)
>
> exec :dbname := '&1'
>
> print :dbname

I guess this is related to your [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29405527/3989608). You don't need to **define the bind variable, assign and print the value** if you are again using it in the SELECT statement as a **substitution variable**.

Do it like this:

```
SQL> set colsep ',';
SQL> set trimout off;
SQL> set pagesize 0;
SQL> set trimspool off;
SQL> set feedback off;
SQL> set heading on;
SQL> var dbname varchar2(20)
SQL> select '&dbname',ename, empno from emp where  deptno = 10;
Enter value for dbname: db1
old   1: select '&dbname',ename, empno from emp where  deptno = 10
new   1: select 'db1',ename, empno from emp where  deptno = 10
db1,CLARK     ,      7782
db1,KING      ,      7839
db1,MILLER    ,      7934
SQL>
```

To suppress the substitution variable verification output, you need `SET VERIFY OFF`

For example,

```
SQL> SET VERIFY OFF
SQL> select '&dbname',ename, empno from emp where  deptno = 10;
Enter value for dbname: db1
db1,CLARK     ,      7782
db1,KING      ,      7839
db1,MILLER    ,      7934
SQL>
```

**Update** Error logging

You could use the new SQL*Plus error logging feature. I have written an article, have a look at it http://lalitkumarb.wordpress.com/2014/01/21/sqlplus-error-logging-new-feature-release-11-1/

Comment: i dont want such things in output-> old   1: select '&dbname',ename, empno from emp where  deptno = 10
new   1: select 'db1',ename, empno from emp where  deptno = 10

Comment: `set errorlogging on;` Read the article properly, everything is mentioned in details. And please mark the answer as answered.